# Bijection between $SO(3)$ and $S^2\times S^1$

Tags: general-topology, matrices, smooth-manifolds

$SO(3)$ and $S^2\times S^1$ are in a set bijection because of having the same cardinality. Tapp in his *Matrix groups* book informally "defines" $SO(3)$ as "all positions of a globe on a fixed stand" and then asks:

> **Question** Is there a natural bijection between $SO(3)$ and $S^2\times S^1$?

When I was reading this I thought the answer should be Yes, because each position of a (unit) globe is determined by first placing the north pole at its correct place, say $p$, and then applying a rotation to the globe around $OP$.

However, later in the book Tapp writes:

$SO(3)$ is not homeomorphic to $S^2\times S^1$ which implies a negative answer to the **Question**.

I understand that the author has intentionally been vague at the beginning of the book, but I still wonder whether the map that I have described above can count as at least a discontinuous (natural) bijection between $S^2\times S^1$ and $SO(3)$.

As a separate, but related question, what are the most elementary (resp. quickest) ways of seeing that $S^2\times S^1$ and $SO(3)$ are not homeomorphic or diffeomorphic.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I don't really know what you consider elementary, but: the fundamental group of $S^{2} \times S^{1}$ is isomorphic to $\pi_{1}(S^{2}) \times \pi_{1}(S^{1}) \cong \mathbb{Z}$, whereas $\pi_{1}(SO(3)) \cong \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$, so they cannot be homeomorphic.

Comment: There is certainly a bijection, but I have no idea in what sense such a thing would be natural. As has been pointed out, the spaces can not be homeomorphic since, e.g. they have different fundamental groups.

Comment: @Mike Pierce I'm surprised that you edited my question the second time to delete "Thanks a lot!" from the bottom. Is there any problem with thanking people who take the time to read my question and/or leave comments? Thanks!

Comment: @Simon My opinion was that it just creates noise in your question to say thank you; if you ask a good question here, I think it's safe to assume you are thankful for anyone who answers. I've found [this post though](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9653/167197), so I rolled back my edit.

Comment: For your "separate but related" question, I think the quickest proof that SO$(3)$ is not homeomorphic to $S^2\times S^1$ is to quote the (definitely not elementary) theorem that the second homotopy group of any Lie group is trivial.  (I don't yet have a candidate for the most elementary proof.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your idea of first placing the north pole in its intended position $p$ is good; it defines a map from $\text{SO}(3)$ onto $S^2$.  Furthermore, for each fixed $p$, the subset of $\text{SO}(3)$ that maps to $p$ (i.e., the positions of the sphere that have the north pole at location $p$) form, as you said, a circle $C_p$, since they correspond to the possibilities for rotating the sphere around the axis through $p$.  The problem is that there is no continuous way to identify each of these circles with $S^1$.  By itself, each of these circles is a copy of $S^1$, but there is no way to choose homeomorphisms $S^1\to C_p$ for all $p$ in a way that is continuous as $p$ varies.